# Apache ActiveMQ Connect to a topic non-dynamically

Tags: java, static, jms, activemq-classic

I've set up ActiveMQ and I can create/connect to a topic using "dynamicTopics/MyTopic". This works great:

```
    Properties env = new Properties( );
    env.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory");
    env.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"tcp://myhostname:xxxxx");
    javax.naming.Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

    InitialContext jndi = new InitialContext(env);

    // Look up a JMS connection factory
    TopicConnectionFactory conFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory)jndi.lookup("TopicConnectionFactory");

    // Create a JMS connection
    TopicConnection connection = conFactory.createTopicConnection(username,password);

    Topic chatTopic = (Topic)jndi.lookup("dynamicTopics/MyTopic");
```

I would like to connect to a topic already exists without dynamically creating the topic if it doesn't exist, how can I do so?

Cheers,

Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you don't need to create destinations manually with AMQ you always have that option.  Basically you can alter the security settings to allow only an admin to create destinations.  See the AMQ FAQ for this:

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-create-new-destinations.html

Regards

Tim
www.fusesource.com

Answer (score 0):

What you are actually doing is just connecting to topic. ActiveMQ is so nice that it creates topic for you if it did not exist before.

So, to connect to already existing topic just do the same that you are already doing.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, but I *do not* want ActiveMQ to create the topic for me if it does not exist. How can I achieve that?